# vectorizing two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

Hey guys I want do add two vector,the following should happen

```
Vec1 = [1 3 5 7 9]
Vec2 = [2 4 6 8]


Vec = Vec1 + Vec2  = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Hence, the ith number of Vec2 should come between the ith and i+1 index of vec1

I've tried doing this using a for loop and using even and odd indexing. However it did not work.

Also, doing it manually is not a option. The real vectors which I am using are quite big.

does anyone have a tip? or knows how to do it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: just a general note, this question was answered so many times now, so it's either that people are not searching the right words because the terms used are wrong or vague (like the title of this question) or that they need the personal touch from someone to answer them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would call that concatenation not addition. You want to assign `vec1` to all of the odd locations in the new vector and `vec2` to all of the even locations. We can do that this way.

```
% We can pre-allocate the output
new = zeros(1, numel(vec1) + numel(vec2));

% Assign vec1 to all of the odd locations (all other slots remain 0)
new(1:2:(numel(vec1)*2)) = vec1;

% Assign vec2 to all of the even locations 
new(2:2:(numel(vec2)*2)) = vec2;

%   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

If `vec1` and `vec2` are  the same size, we can just use `cat` followed by a `reshape`.

```
new = reshape(cat(1, vec1, vec2), 1, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Vec1 = [1 3 5 7 9]
Vec2 = [2 4 6 8]

vec = [vec1 vec2]
sort(vec)
```

The result will be the two vectors concatenated and sorted:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values OP used are just to illustrate.